# Is Administratium an actual word?

Tags: vocabulary, neologisms, is-it-a-word

We commonly use this word in office, and the [definitions point](http://geekdictionary.computing.net/define/administratium) to its meaning.

But is this an actual word? It's not in the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Comment: It's a joke. [A joke chemical element.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Flooglepz* is a word: I just invented it. Until a few seconds ago I was the only person who used it and knew of it.

A few more people know about the word *administratium*.

Neither of these words are generally accepted English words — however the set of words that are considered English words is not a set with clear undisputed boundaries. Personally, if it’s in the OED, I’ll consider it an official English word, and if it isn’t I won’t. In the next edition of OED, *administratium* might conceivably make the transition from a joke word used by a few people to a joke word used widely enough to become an English word (by my definition).

Comment: I cannot find on the Internet, a definition of 'flooglepz'.
I have to say, I am a little surprised.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it depends on the population. The question "Is *x* a word" is meaningless without reference to a population. If the population is taken as your office coworkers, then yes it most definitely is a word. For larger populations, I would say that it is not a "real" word.

Answer (score 4):

If you google it, Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administratium) says

> Administratium is a well-known joke in scientific circles...A similar joke concerns Administrontium which was referenced in print in 1993"

Although the points above about relation to population are accurate.